# Apache Camel reactive streams with Bindy - only reading first line

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I'm trying to use Apache Camel (version 2.25.3) reactive streams in combination with Spring Boot to read a large csv file and unmarshal the lines using Bindy. This is "working" in the sense that the application runs and detects files as they appear but I then only see the first line of the file in my stream. It appears to be Bindy related because if I take the unmarshalling out of the equation I get back all the lines of the csv file in my stream just fine. I have simplified the problem to demonstrate here on SO. I'm using Spring Webflux to expose the resulting Publisher.

So my Camel route is as follows:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.reactive.streams.api.CamelReactiveStreamsService;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TransactionLineCsvRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    private final CamelReactiveStreamsService camelRs;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        var bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(LineItem.class);

        from("file:input/?include=.*\\.csv&move=successImport&moveFailed=failImport")
                .unmarshal(bindy)
                .to("reactive-streams:lineItems");
    }

    public Flux<LineItem> getLineItemFlux() {
        Publisher<LineItem> lineItems = camelRs.fromStream("lineItems", LineItem.class);

        return Flux.from(lineItems);
    }
}
```

The Bindy class:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@CsvRecord(separator = ";", skipFirstLine = true, skipField =true)
public class LineItem {
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String description;
}
```

And the endpoint to expose the Flux:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/lineItems", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<LineItem> lineItems() {
    return lineItemFlux;
}
```

So when I now do my curl:

```
curl localhost:8080/lineItems
```

I only get back the first line whereas when I remove the ".unmarshal(bind)" line (and refactor the stream to be of type String instead of LineItem) I get back all the elements of the csv file.

So I guess I'm not using Bindy correct within the reactive streams context. I followed this [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/reactive-streams-component.html#_request_a_transformation_to_camel) and tried to rewrite my route as follows:

```
from("file:input/?include=.*\\.csv&move=successImport&moveFailed=failImport")
        .to("reactive-streams:rawLines");

from("reactive-streams:rawLines")
        .unmarshal(bindy)
        .to("reactive-streams:lineItems");
```

It shows the routes are started correctly:

```
2021-01-04 10:13:26.798  INFO 26438 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: file://input/?include=.*%5C.csv&move=successImport&moveFailed=failImport
2021-01-04 10:13:26.800  INFO 26438 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route2 started and consuming from: reactive-streams://rawLines
2021-01-04 10:13:26.801  INFO 26438 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
```

But then I get an exception stating "The stream has no active subscriptions":

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [file://input/?include=.*%5C.csv&move=successImport&moveFailed=failImport      ] [         9]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [reactive-streams:rawLines                                                     ] [         5]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The stream has no active subscriptions
    at org.apache.camel.component.reactive.streams.engine.CamelPublisher.publish(CamelPublisher.java:108) ~[camel-reactive-streams-2.25.3.jar:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.reactive.streams.engine.DefaultCamelReactiveStreamsService.sendCamelExchange(DefaultCamelReactiveStreamsService.java:144) ~[camel-reactive-streams-2.25.3.jar:2.25.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.reactive.streams.ReactiveStreamsProducer.process(ReactiveStreamsProducer.java:52) ~[camel-reactive-streams-2.25.3.jar:2.25.3]
```

Does anyone have any pointers how I might use Bindy in combination with reactive streams? Thanks!

**EDIT**

After the very helpful post from burki I was able to fix my code. So the route definition changed to the following. As you can see I removed the unmarshal step, so it just picks up files from the file system as they arrive and puts them in a reactive stream:

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    from("file:input/?include=.*\\.csv&move=successImport&moveFailed=failImport")
            .to("reactive-streams:extractedFile");
}
```

And then expose the file stream as a Flux:

```
public Flux<File> getFileFlux() {
    return Flux.from(camelRs.fromStream("extractedFile", File.class));
}
```

And the code to parse the CSV is as follows (using OpenCSV as burki suggested but using a different part of the API):

```
private Flux<LineItem> readLineItems() {
    return fileFlux
            .flatMap(message -> Flux.using(
                    () -> new CsvToBeanBuilder<LineItem>(createFileReader(message)).withSkipLines(1)
                            .withSeparator(';')
                            .withType(LineItem.class)
                            .build()
                            .stream(),
                    Flux::fromStream,
                    BaseStream::close)
            );
}

private FileReader createFileReader(File file) {
    System.out.println("Reading file from: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        return new FileReader(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

You can now expose this resulting Flux as an endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/lineItems", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<LineItem> lineItems() {
    return readLineItems();
}
```

And now when you do the curl like I did above you get the full unmarshalled LineItems from the csv.

I still have as a todo whether or not this actually loads the entire file into memory or not. I don't think so, I think I only get a pointer to the file which I then stream to the OpenCSV bean but I need to verify this, could be that I'm now first reading the entire file into memory and then streaming it which would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the file consumer just pass **the whole file** to the unmarshalling step.

Therefore if you unmarshal the result of the file consumer to a `LineItem`, you **"reduce" the whole file content to the first line**.

If you in contrast remove the unmarshalling you get the whole file content. But probably the file consumer loaded the **whole file into memory before passing it on**.

But reading the whole file is not what you want. To **read the CSV file line by line** you need to split the file in streaming mode.

```
from("file:...")
    .split(body().tokenize(LINE_FEED)).streaming()
    .to("direct:processLine")
```

Like this, the [Splitter](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html) sends every line to the route `direct:processLine` for further processing.

The problem I faced in this scenario was to **parse a single CSV line**. Most of the CSV libraries are designed to read and parse entire files, not single lines.

However the quite old [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) lib has a [`CSVParser`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) with a `parseLine(String csvLine)` method. So I used this to parse a "completely detached" single CSV line.

Comment: Awesome, thanks burki, going to check it out!

Comment: That was the hint I needed burki, thanks again! I'll post my solution in an edit above for others who might find it interesting.